# Disable Kaspersky in the middle?

Tags: kaspersky

I have notices, that often my webpages hanged in Chrome with the following status message:

[image]

Is it possible to disable Kaspersky from inserting any (glitching) code into web pages?

Comment: Disable the feature

Answer (score 1):

In the main Kaspersky window,  click the "Settings" icon (an image of a gear), and select the `Protection` settings.

Disable the item named `Web Anti-virus`. Kaspersky will bug you about it a bit, so when given the option, select "Ignore" to prevent further messages.

Depending on your browser, Kaspersky may have installed several add-ons. Disable/remove them if you like, though they should be inane now that the main component has been disabled.

Comment: I don't want to disable antivirus. I wish it check unencrypted traffic, but does not insert it's own javascript or somethinmg

Comment: that is part of the web-antivirus platform. It checks links and content against its own web-services to see if it is known to be bad before allowing it to execute. This is their way of catching phishing and tracking attack sites. see here: http://support.kaspersky.com/us/11236#block2